# "To get enough feet"?

Tags: expressions

I can't tell what is meant by "to get enough feet".

Here is an example quotation:

> Aug 6, 2014 - But some how not managing **to get enough feet** through our doors. I don't have a budget for marketing but get told I am not marketing enough.

Comment: You need the whole thing: "Get a foot through the door". You could try Googling "Get a foot _in_ the door" to see if that helps.

Comment: it's worth noting that ...well see the final pp of my answer!

Comment: It's the brick-and-mortar counterpart to the digital expression "to attract enough eyeballs to our site." Both the feet and the eyeballs are attached to human beings, who presumably are attached to wallets and/or purses with cash and/or credit cards in them.

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like the person who wrote this was intending to use [metonymy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metonymy). Not managing to "get enough feet through our doors" seems like it is intending to convey that the business is not getting enough *foot traffic*.

> **Foot traffic**: A term used to describe pedestrian visitors to a business or commercial site. Foot traffic refers to those who are
>   exposed to a commercial establishment, whether they walk past or into
>   an establishment or drive by the building.

- [BusinessDictionary.com](http://www.businessdictionary.com/definition/foot-traffic.html)

Those types of idiomatic phrases, relating to feet, refer to the number of physical people coming in and out of the business, whether they are customers, visitors, etc.

Answer (score 1):

"Feet" here is being used as a synonym for people. I would guess from the context its meaning is more specifically potential customers to the business being written about.

The implication of using "feet" instead of "people" is that the business relies on a high volume of traffic for sales. "Feet" describes activity at the store and would probably be a useful piece of knowledge in better understanding sales figures.

Answer (score 0):

> "get feet through the doors"

is a completely commonplace, very well-known, marketing term.

You can trivially google examples,

https://www.google.com/#q=%22get+feet+through+the+doors%22

for example,

http://www.quora.com/Is-it-possible-to-grow-a-business-with-no-marketing

> "promotions based on buying habits get feet through the doors during quiet periods"

The quoted passage is simply a variation on that.

(Another very similar, and funny, phrase is "get asses on seats!" (ie, get paying customers.))

Note that saying "get your foot in the door" means, basically, you got a starter position (a job) at a company, your first job; whereas "get feet through doors" refers to a retail business getting customers to come in the doors.